# LaTeX Beamer: Create own variable

Tags: beamer

I am trying to create an own variable like `\author{}` or `\date{}` in the LaTeX Beamer class. I need it for a title image that I use multiple times in the document. In the preamble I would like to specify the path to that image like
`\setTitleImage{path/to/image}` and then in the document it should be possible to get that path by using `\titleImage`. I tried it with `\newcommand{}`
 but somehow it won't work as expected.
Does anybody have an idea of how to do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Daniel

Comment: Can you edit your question and add [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) with what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`beamer-fuberlin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer-fuberlin) theme defines commands `\titlegraphic` and `\inserttitlegraphic` which can do what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode
<all>
{
  \renewcommand\titlegraphic[2][]{%
    \edef\inserttitlegraphic{%
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\else
        \noexpand\includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
      \fi}%
    }%
  \titlegraphic{}
}

\titlegraphic[width=5cm,keepaspectratio]{images/valley}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\inserttitlegraphic{}
\titlegraphic[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\inserttitlegraphic{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\inserttitlegraphic
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your general question

> I am trying to create an own variable like \author{} or \date{} in the LaTeX Beamer class.

e.g., with a variable containing a supervisor, we can define the following:

```
\newcommand\insertsupervisor{}  % Empty by default.
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\renewcommand\insertsupervisor{#1}}
```

We can now use `\supervisor{}` in the preamble, just like we would use `\author{}`.
To display the (content of) supervisor, we can use `\insertsupervisor`.